# using another javascript class within a different class

Tags: javascript, html, class

In Swift I can instantiate one class within another as a property and call its methods using something like:

```
newClass.anotherClass.methodInTheOtherClass();
```

I am unable to do that in JavaScript. The following code produces an error in this line:

```
var cowCommunication = new CowCommunication();
```

What is the proper way to achieve this goal, and make the following script work?

```
<html >
  <script type = "text/javascript" >
  let CowCommunication = {
    sayMoo: function() {
      alert("hey");
    }
  };
let farmTools = {
  var cowCommunication = new CowCommunication();
};
farmTools.cowCommunication.sayMoo();

</script>
</html >
```

This is a real example of code I am actually trying to make work.

Comment: you can't use the `var` keyword inside of an object initializer in javascript, that's your main problem. look up the correct way to instantiate objects in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let farmTools = {
  cowCommunication : new CowCommunication(),
};
```

Not

```
let farmTools = {
  var cowCommunication = new CowCommunication();
};
```

---

Also :

```
class CowCommunication  {

    sayMoo() {
      alert("hey");
    }
}
```

Not :

```
let CowCommunication = {
    sayMoo: function() {
      alert("hey");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Abdenour!  I tried that and have received test.html:10 Uncaught TypeError: CowCommunication is not a constructor

Comment: is it ok now ? @MarkPurpelio

Comment: brilliant, Abdennour - yes!  One final aspect: right now we have "farmTools.cowCommunication.sayMoo();" working.  What if we wanted ONE MORE level, such as "farmTools.cowCommunication.newLevel.sayMoo();" ?

Comment: `class NewLevel  { sayMoo(){} } ; class CowCommunication { constructor() {this.newLevel= new NewLevel();}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use composition instead of Classes.

```
let cowCommunication = {
    sayMoo: function() {
      console.log('hey')
    }
};

const farmTools = function() {
  return Object.assign({}, cowCommunication)
}

let instance = farmTools()

instance.sayMoo()
```

Comment: thank you!  but you end up with "instance.sayMoo()"  i need "farmTools.cowCommunication.sayMoo();" i need to the dots, the second class, and the method from the second class, so to speak

Comment: The method is actually from the second object, it's just not notated that way; it's just inherited from the first object by way of prototypes, which is sort of the Class system of JS.